# Processing stopped during data migration

Tags: magento2, data-migration

Processing stopped during data migration.
I don't know how to fix it.

Could you tell me?

Command executed:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.1/config.xml
```

Message when processing has stopped:

```
[Exception] Notice: Undefined offset: 151 in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 813
```

All messages being processed

```
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-04 09:29:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
71% [====================>-------] Remaining Time: < 1 sec

[Exception] Notice: Undefined offset: 151 in /var/www/html/tertiary/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 813
```

Comment: Have you tried migrating again in a fresh Magento instance?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have an `attribute_id` in the source database table `catalog_eav_attribute` and/or `eav_entity_attribute` which no longer exists in the `eav_attribute` table. The undefined offset is the attribute ID.

You can remove this row from the `catalog_eav_attribute` table and try again!